# python determine the system PATH system agnosticly

Tags: python, path, python-2.7, operating-system, environment-variables

A program that I am writing needs to determine if certain other programs are installed on the system.  Specifically a command line program to generate a hash value.  Since there are so many possible versions of these programs, I need to check for the major ones only (md5, whirlpool, etc).

The program I'm writing is system agnostic, and meant to run on any win/mac/*nix.

I want to be able to do a fast search of the OS's standard $PATH, but I do not know how to retrieve that information (the contents of $PATH) from system to system.

Searches here turned up only material on finding python's path, or the path of the currently running script.

Would anyone have a solution, or be able to point me to cross platform solution to this?

Comment: @Mike: he's not asking about python path..

Comment: Mike, `PYTHONPATH` is not the same as `PATH`.  Simplified, `PYTHONPATH` adds to the locations where Python looks for modules when importing while `PATH` is an operating system list of locations to search for executables.

Comment: @Mike - not really, python path is a `sys.path` variable, rather than `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` which can be undefined in some edge cases. On the other hand `sys.path` might include paths that aren't on your `PYTHONPATH` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be quite cross-platform, unless I'm overlooking something obvious:

Linux example:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['PATH']
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

MacOS example:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['PATH']
/Users/vlazarenko/bin:/Users/vlazarenko/SDK/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Windows example:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['PATH']
C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\Windows\system3
2;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\M
icrosoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DT
S\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Serv
er\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual S
tudio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Se
rver\100\DTS\Binn\
>>>
```

Comment: I would add `.split(os.pathsep)` to the end of the print command. Gives you a nice list

Comment: So on all three major systems the variable is actually PATH?  I wasn't sure if that was the  case which is why I didn't go this way.  (No access to a mac and been windows free for 10 years...)

Comment: Mac is for sure `$PATH`, my example is from a mac :) Windows is `%PATH%`, let me just quickly test that for you.

Comment: But be aware that the value of `$PATH` on Unix-y systems, including OS X, is often changed by users in their shell profiles.  And, if a program is run under a GUI environment in OS X or as a daemon, `$PATH` may have different values than if run from a "login" shell.  The point is that the value of `$PATH` may vary depending on the context your program is running in.  That may or may not be significant for your use case but you should keep it in mind.